# Make Object Move To Mouse Position without pass through other object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am making one game like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06b0-pwuyKQ

On this, I must moving 1 object with touch dragable, when drag this object, it can not pass through other object.

First time, i try to use boxcollider and rigidbody, then lerp object to mouse position. Unfortunately, object draging always pass through other object.

So i try to create grid map, have all object in game, then when moving any object, i check current position of object with neighbor object of this, for now it's up, down, left and right, then clamp its position with neighbor. It work! But with diagonal neighbor object, it is still pass through.

So, i decide to create this topic to ask:

How can i clamp position of object with diagonal neighbor object?
or have any solution to move object-rigidbody without pass through other?

Below is video demo and 1 part of code to clamp object position of me.

Thank you very much!

Code: pastebin.com/mSrQjQmn 
Video: facebook.com/jim.dum.5/videos/450488961822806/

Comment: it's incredibly difficult to do this Jim.  you have to seek and find free paths to the target.  just to experiment, try this:  when you put the finger down, mark that object as the one you are moving.  then **apply force** to the object (never just move it).  this will make it "bounce around" other fixed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Lerp bypasses colliders. I think you should solve this problem by scripting.

```
public class StopMoving()
{
public bool canLerp;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
{
   if (other.tag == "yourTag")
    {
      canLerp = false;
    }
}
}
```

You should make canLerp a requirement for your Lerp. So you can stop it when a collider is hit. You can use any way of identifying the right object. I used tag as an example. Don't forget to change `canLerp` to true to resume lerping to the mouse position.